# Does a power button of USB-C dock brand X work on laptop of brand Y?

Tags: laptop, usb-c, docking-station

I currently have an HP laptop and an HP USB-C docking station.

I also have an opportunity to purchase a powerful used Dell laptop for a reasonably cheap price.

I understand that USB-C docking stations are not specific to brands: for example, the DisplayPort/HDMI data is sent over DisplayPort alt mode, which is standardized. Also everything else is attached via USB.

So I think that my HP docking station should work with any laptop that has USB-C DisplayPort alt mode.

However, the HP docking station has a power button. Does this power button work on laptops of other brands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could, but there's no guarantee.

At work, we actually work with USB-C docks, and we even work with those of HP, and DELL so this is something that I've had to deal with.

The biggest problem with USB-C docks is their power requirements. Some docks require at least 65 watt of power, where others require 90 watt of power.

It may be obvious that a USB-C dock that requires 90 watt of power, will not work with a 65 watt of power, but if you already figured that out, you would probably not have asked the question.

In terms of interchangeability, as long as the connector is the right one, and the watt requirement is at least what the dock needs, then it will work. At least, for HP laptops.

If the watt requirement is too low, the dock may still work, but stop working the moment you add things like a 2nd screen, etc. Also, it may work correctly with all screens etc, but simply won't be able to charge the laptop, so even though its plugged in, the power drains slowly, rather than charging the laptop.

As for working with other brands, this is not always the case. The dock will require drivers, and HP installs them natively on their system. Some laptops don't install all drivers for all hp docks either, but in those cases you can still download and install the drivers. For non-hp brands, it may or may not work. I've seen cases where the HP framework needed to be installed alongside with the drivers and even then, it did not always work correctly. Different versions of different drivers sometimes made a difference.

Because of that, we looked further and found a DELL dock that seems to just always work. For HP laptops we still use HP docks though.

As for the power button, I'm fairly sure that is just there to turn the dock on and off, and not to control the laptop itself.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there is no standard protocol for the power button on USB-C docks. Other than @LPChip assumed, the power button on HP docks is actually able to turn on a laptop or put it to sleep. I use it to turn on my HP laptop with its lid closed in order to only work with the two connected monitors and not have to deal with application windows opening on the small laptop screen.

Unfortunately, I have no experience with the HP dock and a Dell laptop but I would not be surprised it they are incompatible regarding the power button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).